# How to generate (in MATLAB) all collections of n subsets of 1:v?

Tags: matlab

So for example, given 
    n=3 
and 
    v=2, 
then I would want the function to generate:

```
{[1],[1],[1]}
{[1],[1],[2]}
{[1],[2],[2]}
{[2],[2],[2]}
{[1],[1],[1,2]}
{[1],[1,2],[2]}
{[1],[1,2],[1,2]}
{[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]}
{[1,2],[1,2],[2]}
{[1,2],[2],[2]}
```

As you can see I want to allow repetition in the 
    n 
elements of each collection but no repetition within each subset (ie 
    {[1],[1]} 
is allowed but 
    {[1,1]} 
is not).

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why {1,[1,2],2} is the only value that is not ordered ? Is that a mistake ?

Comment: @obchardon It doesn't really matter what order the function outputs the sets in, but in my context a<b iff min(a)<max(b) (obviously this is not a total ordering).

Comment: and why {2,[1,2],[1,2]} is not part of the set ? (for example)

Comment: Sorry, it should be, I forgot a few elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nchoosek` using a [small tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) for generating the repetition:

```
k = 2 
%n is directly determined by k. for k = 3 you will already have 92378 collections of subsets.
%for k = 4, you better have the fastest supercomputer on earth...
n = nchoosek(2*k-1,k)

%generate all possible combination with repetition for n = 3
comb1 = nchoosek(1:2*n-1,n)-[0:n-1]
%generate all possible combination with repetition for k = 2
comb2 = nchoosek(1:2*k-1,k)-([0:k-1]+[k-1:-1:0])
%All the combination are know transformed into cell of size  1 x (nchoosek(2*k-1,k))
comb2 = mat2cell(uint8(comb2),ones(nchoosek(2*k-1,k),1),k)
%uint8 to convert negative value to 0, you can also use uint16, uint32...

res = reshape(comb2(comb1,:),nchoosek(2*n-1,n),n).';
```

Noticed that with this method, each cell have the same size 1 x k and can contain a zero. So for example this
cell `{[1],[1],[1,2]}` will be `{[0,1],[0,1],[1,2]}`.

```
res:

{[0 1][0 1][0 1]}
{[0 1][0 1][0 2]}
{[0 1][0 1][1 2]}
{[0 1][0 2][0 2]}
{[0 1][0 2][1 2]}
{[0 1][1 2][1 2]}
{[0 2][0 2][0 2]}
{[0 2][0 2][1 2]}
{[0 2][1 2][1 2]}
{[1 2][1 2][1 2]}
```

If you really want to get rid of 0 value, then a small `cellfun` will do the job:

```
res = cellfun(@(x)nonzeros(x),res,'UniformOutput',0)

res:

{[1][1][1]}
{[1][1][2]}
{[1][1][1 2]}
{[1][2][2]}
{[1][2][2]}
{[1][2][1 2]}
{[2][2][2]}
{[2][2][1 2]}
{[2][1 2][1 2]}
{[1 2][1 2][1 2]}
```

Also `n` cannot be set randomly `n` should be equal to the number of combination of `comb2`. So `n = nchoosek(2*k-1,k)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a huge help! :)

Comment: Sorry, one small thing - for some reason when I run this function I get two copies of {[1] [1] [1]} and no copies of {[1] [1] [2]}, any idea of why this might be?

Comment: missed a matrix transposition, fixed now.

Comment: Ho and by the way, `n` cannot be set randomly, `n` should be `n = nchoosek(2*k-1,k)`